# Assign doesn't work in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, assign

I use prestashop 1.5.4, 
I tried to assign variables to smarty like this but it doesn't work, i debugged all variables with var_dump and ther's no problem.
I have a blank page with only this code

```
<div id="block_various_links_footer" class="block_various_links">
    <p class="title_block">Information</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="first_item"></li></ul></div>
```

I commented the assign instruction and the website return to work.

```
public function hookdisplayHome($params) {

$id_cms= Configuration::get('MOD_CMS_READ_MORE_ID_CMS')?intval(Configuration::get('MOD_CMS_READ_MORE_ID_CMS')):1;

$id_lang = (int)Context::getContext()->language->id;

$cms = new CMS($id_cms,$id_lang);
$link  = Context::getContext()->link;


$nb_char = Configuration::get('MOD_CMS_READ_MORE_NB_CHARS')?intval(Configuration::get('MOD_CMS_READ_MORE_NB_CHARS')):30;
$cms_cont = $cms->content;

$link_cms = $link->getCMSLink($id_cms);
```

$this->context->smarty->assign(array('link'=>$link_cms,'nbstr'=>$nb_char,'cms_content'=>$cms_cont));

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'CMS_ARTICLE_PART.tpl');
```

}

my tpl CMS_ARTICLE_PART.tpl file

```
<div>
<p>{if isset($cms_content) && $cms_content}{$cms_content|truncate:$nbstr}{/if}</p>
<a href="{if isset($link) && $link}{$link}{/if}">read more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: what tells you the assign doesn't work? From your template's code you're not using the variables

Comment: I assigned link, and it's a global smarty variable, i changed its name and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the "dev mode" of Prestashop by settings "_PS_MODE_DEV_" to "true" (in config/defines.inc.php).

It will let Prestashop display PHP errors, to help you debug your problem.

If an error is displayed, you can paste it here.

Comment: the mode dev is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was the assigned link variable , it's a global smarty variable, i changed its name